# I want to know how to pass an array into a method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have tried a few times already here's what I have so far:

```
    public void turnOn(int index, spotlights[]){
    spotlights[index]=2;
    currentStatus=2;
    }
```

Here's my array definition:

```
    private Spotlight[] spotlights = new Spotlight[20];
```

There are twenty lights and I'm changing one (index) to on or currentStatus to become 2.

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: `public void turnOn(int index, Spotligh[] spotlights)`

Comment: I've tried that also but get a "spotlights cannot be resolved to a type" error. I don't know why

Comment: Probably, as Spotlight is some class, `spotlights[index].value = 2;`. Maybe it was `int[] spotlights = new int[20];`?

Comment: Worked assylias, thanks :)

Comment: Why that one was accepted? It has at least 2 syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void turnOn(int index, Spotlight[] spotlights)
```

Comment: Thanks rcompanhoni, will accept in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

```
public void turnOn(int index, Spotlight[] name){
    spotlights = name;
    spotlights[index]=2;
    currentStatus=2;
}
```

Pass `spotlights` array to your `turnOn` method or you can use the method variable directly.

```
public void turnOn(int index, Spotlight[] spotlights){
        spotlights[index]=2;
        currentStatus=2;
    }
```

Comment: `name` does not match to `spotlights`

Comment: I meant to show that he wasn't passing an argument name in the parameters list. Sorry i wasn't complete in my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
public void turnOn(int index, Spotlight[] spotlights) {
    spotlights[index].setCurrentStatus(2);
}
```

Notice that you should have a `setCurrentStatus(int)` method on `Spotlight` class.